# Servicestack cool uri's not resolving when deployed

Tags: routes, servicestack

We are working successfully with cool uri's in development (SS v3.9.64, Visual Studio 2012, Framework 3.5), for instance:

```
Routes.Add<Bark>("/bark.ashx/{dogname}", "GET");
```

But when we deploy it we just can get it working with querystring. We get a "Handler for Request not found" when using urls like:

```
http://localhost:51781/IrpfWebApi/bark.ashx/sprocket
```

We reproduce this issue by just publishing the project to local and running it from Visual Studio 2012 (it is supposed to be the same server).

We use the .ashx extension in order to be able to work in W2003 / IIS6 as it is explained in several places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ashx` extension required for IIS 6 is supposed to be apart of the Handler Path not the route, e.g:

```
  <!-- ServiceStack: Required to host at: /api.ashx -->
  <location path="api.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <!-- Required for IIS7 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <!-- Required for MONO -->
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="api.ashx*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS7 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ServiceStack: Required -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then your Route registrations would just be:

```
Routes.Add<Bark>("/bark/{dogname}", "GET");
```